# Some knows how to view the java console

Tags: java, jar, console

I want to view the java console externally to a IDE (eclipse),
I mean, I have a jar and it runs the application, but i couldn't see the errors

I already do the control panel thing,

Thanks for the help

Comment: How are you running your JAR? From a command prompt window? Also, which OS are you on?

Comment: Windows  7, I run it with double-click, like a exe

Answer (score 3):

Run it from a command window instead of double clicking it and you should be able to see the console output.

```
java -jar path_to_your_jar
```

Comment: Is there a way to record the data showed in the command window into a String array within a different jar?

Answer (score 0):

On windows XP, there is a java tray icon when executing a jar file. You can open console from it. I don't know if it still works on windows 7.

[image]

Comment: it doesnt appear, but thanks for your answer